# VS2013 is having trouble with base class being in unnamed namespace

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

The following code compiles fine and runs as expected:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace
{
    struct Base
    {
        void print() const { std::cout << "test"; };
    };
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.print();
    return 0;
}
```

But when looking at d during runtime using QuickWatch, IntelliSense seems to be unable to find
Base.

I solved this by putting Base in a named namespace instead of an unnamed.

So is it a bug in Visual Studio, or am I missing something out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem with anonymous namepaces has been an issue in VC++ for a while - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0888kc6a%28VS.80%29.aspx.  From the linked doc:

> The native C++ expression evaluator does not support anonymous namespaces.

and

> The only way to watch the symbol test in this example is to use the decorated name:

e.g. `(int*)?test@?A0xccd06570@mars@@3HA` (using the namespace hierarchy given in the example to illustrate the point).  Just use the decorated name? That's so convenient! Thanks, Microsoft.

Comment: @Drop: it makes you wonder what the internal word for "Standard" is.